# bypass IE browser message "To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information" using vba

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

How this message can be avoided after refreshing the web page using  `IE.Refresh` 
or
`IE.Document.Location.Reload(True)`.

The following has been tried but did not work :

```
Win_Dialog = FindWindow(vbnullString, "Windows Internet Explorer")

If Win_Dialog <> 0 then
   Dlg_ChildWin = FindWindowEx(Win_Dialog, 0&, "BUTTON", "&Retry")
   If Dlg_ChildWin <> 0 then
      SendMessage(Dlg_ChildWin, BM_CLICK, &H0, &H0)
   EndIf
EndIf
```

Although `Win_Dialog <> 0`  and `Dlg_ChildWin <> 0` the code did not work.

Comment: *Sheepishly mentions* you can use the `.SendKeys` method if all else fails...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The following also tried but it does not always work:    Appactivate "Windows Internet Explorer",True     Sendkeys " ", True

Comment: Mostly this message appears, when you are trying to activate `javascript:__doPostBack` element. When you are getting this error message?

Comment: IE.Navigate UrlName                 Do DoEvents Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE          After exiting this loop, the pop up message appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer this example may help you to close that confirm popup.

```
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: TimeoutCheck: Loop
Sleep (3000)
apiShowWindow ie.hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL


Call ieDoc.parentWindow.execScript("window.confirm = function onUpdatedShowAlertTS(varControl) {return true}", "JavaScript")
```

Reference:

[VBA Close Java Alerts Popups with name "Message from webpage"](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47073-VBA-Close-Java-Alerts-Popups-with-name-quot-Message-from-webpage-quot)

Comment: I have noticed that 
AppActivate "Windows Internet Explorer", True
does not work, maybe because the popup window is already active.
So by removing this and simply use
SendKeys " ", True
the popup window closes.

It also works by replacing 
AppActivate "Windows Internet Explorer", True
with
ShowWindow Dlg_ChildWIN, SW_SHOWNORMAL

I was just wondering if there is a way to avoid this popup window at all.
Using the flag parameter of IE.Navigate (1:clear browsing history, 2:clear cookies , &H80:clear webpage recovery data  etc.) had no result.
Or maybe the Postdata parameter ?

Comment: There is no any other way to avoid the pop up. You have to handle the pop up using the code as I show you above. Other wise you need to modify the site code to avoid this pop up.